# Nav walker class error on WordPress update

Tags: walker

I updated my WordPress to Version 4.5 yesterday, and the below warnings were show

```
Warning: Declaration of Walker_Nav_Menu_Dropdown::end_lvl(&$output, $depth) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in /homepages/7/d610643512/htdocs/clickandbuilds/chattepoilue/wp-content/themes/novavideo/_front/mobile-nav.php on line 0

Warning: Declaration of Walker_Nav_Menu_Dropdown::end_el(&$output, $item, $depth) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in /homepages/7/d610643512/htdocs/clickandbuilds/chattepoilue/wp-content/themes/novavideo/_front/mobile-nav.php on line 0
```

Here is the code from file described in the error :

```
class Walker_Nav_Menu_Dropdown extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
  $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth); // don't output children opening tag ('<ul>')
}

function end_lvl(&$output, $depth){
  $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth); // don't output children closing tag
}

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args){
  // add spacing to the title based on the depth
  $item->title  = str_repeat("&nbsp;", $depth * 4) . $item->title;
  $class_names  = isset( $class_names ) ? $class_names : null;
  $indent       = isset( $indent ) ? $indent : null;
  $value        = isset( $value ) ? $value : null;
  $item_output  = isset( $item_output ) ? $item_output : null;


    $output .= '<option'. $indent . $value . $class_names;  
    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '"' : '';  
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) . '"' : '';  
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) . '"' : '';  
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' value="'  . esc_attr( $item->url        ) . '"' : '';  

    $item_output .= $attributes . '>';  
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );  
    $item_output .= '';  

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );    

  // no point redefining this method too, we just replace the li tag...
  $output = str_replace('<li', '<option', $output);
}

function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth){
  $output .= "</option>\n"; // replace closing </li> with the option tag
}
```

}

Comment: It's telling you that your parameters don't match ***exactly*** the parameters from the original class. It then goes on to give you the parameters. So to make this error go away just copy / paste in the parameters it's telling you to

Comment: Yep..by replacing the code, error was removed...Thanks @Howdy_McGee